# Parse City and State from a String

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I'm creating a search similar to the one at yp.com where I need to parse the city name and state name from a text box. City can be multiple words and state can be a full name or abbreviation. There may be a comma between city and state but there also might not be.

Examples:

```
Grand Rapids, New Mexico
Grand Rapids New Mexico
Grand Rapids, NM
Grand Rapids NM
```

This is pretty easy to do if there is a comma involved but I'm not sure at all how to do this if there is no comma.

Comment: you can easily implement a string.Split() on multiple delimiters `,` and `" " ` [MSDN String.Split Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @MethodMan he wants to split cities and countries...not words. IMO, what he wants to do it's not possible unless done manually or unless he uses a white list of cities and countries to compare with

Comment: @Leo good point. I might just need to require that a comma be entered in the city/state search box. I could validate using javascript.

Comment: Match the state first; if the last 'token' is two characters, check against the list of known state abbreviations, if not check against state names.  Once you've found the state, the rest is the city name. Remove whitespace and comma and you're done; of course if they just enter 'New York' you're in a pickle.  Virginia vs. West Virginia is another special case.

Comment: @adamdc78 Good idea, I think if i search the string first for a comma, then I can split it by that and get city and state easy. If there is no comma then split by a blank space. If the last word is 2 digits then I can compare against a list of state abbreviations. Then I can do the same or the last word, then last two words. Only tricky part would be North Carolina and South Carolina, so maybe check the state name list first for the last 2 words and then move onto 1 word state names.

Comment: I would look into APIs for this.  It's an incredibly difficult problem, but one that's been solved by quite a few mapping providers.  Maybe there's a Google Maps or Bing API allowing you to do a text search and get back information about matches.

Comment: something like "Grand Rapids New Mexico" is going to be ambiguous unless you have a list of valid city and state names, or know that multi word states will have particular first words (North, South, New, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintCityState(GetCityState("Grand Rapids, New Mexico"));
        PrintCityState(GetCityState("Sacremento California"));
        PrintCityState(GetCityState("Indianpolis, IN"));
        PrintCityState(GetCityState("Phoenix AZ"));
    }

    public static void PrintCityState(CityState cs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1} ({2})", cs.City, cs.StateAbbreviation, cs.StateName);
    }

    public static CityState GetCityState(string input)
    {
        string truncatedInput = input;
        var statesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"AZ", "Arizona"},
            {"NM", "New Mexico"},
            {"CA", "California"},
            {"WA", "Washington"},
            {"OR", "Oregon"},
            {"MI", "Michigan"},
            {"IN", "Indiana"}
            // And so forth for all 50 states
        };
        var cityState = new CityState();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in statesDictionary)
        {
            if (input.Trim().ToLower().EndsWith(" " + kvp.Key.ToLower()))
            {
                cityState.StateName = kvp.Value;
                cityState.StateAbbreviation = kvp.Key;
                truncatedInput = input.Remove(input.Length - 1 - kvp.Key.Length);
                break;
            }
            if (input.Trim().ToLower().EndsWith(" " + kvp.Value.ToLower()))
            {
                cityState.StateName = kvp.Value;
                cityState.StateAbbreviation = kvp.Key;
                truncatedInput = input.Remove(input.Length - 1 - kvp.Value.Length);
                break;
            }
        }

        cityState.City = truncatedInput.Trim().Trim(',').Trim();
        return cityState;
    }
}

public class CityState
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public string StateAbbreviation { get; set; }
}
```

This code uses a dictionary of state names and abbreviations. I only added 7 states for brevity, but you can add all 50. It searches the input string for a match on either the dictionary keys or dictionary values. If it finds one, it removes the state and whats left is the city.

Make sure you add West Virginia before Virginia in order for it to parse correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It actually required more logic than I thought, but this should be working.

```
var entries = new List<string[]>(); // List of entries
foreach (var e in str.Split('\n')) // Splits by new line .. Can be modified to whatever ...
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e) || !e.Contains(" ")) // If the string is empty, whitespace or doesn't contain a space
        continue; // Skip to next line
    string[] entry; // Entry holder ...
    if (e.Contains(",")) // If the entry contains ","
    {
        entry = e.Split(','); // Split it by ,
        entries.Add(new string[] { entry[1].Trim(), entry[0].Trim() }); // The two entries should be the state and city, so add it to the entries
        continue; // Skip to next line
    }

    entry = e.Split(' '); // Splits the entry by space
    if (entry.Length < 2) // If there is less than two entries
        continue; // Skip to next line

    if (entry.Length > 2) // Checks if there are more than two entries Ex. "Grand Rapids New Mexico"
    {
        var statePart1 = entry[entry.Length - 2]; // Gets the first part of the state
        var statePart2 = entry[entry.Length - 1]; // Gets the second part of the state

        // Note: statePart1 is invalid if the state only has one "word", statePart2 is valid in this case

        if (statePart1 == "North" || statePart1 == "South" || statePart1 == "West" || statePart1 == "New") // Checks if statePart1 is valid
        {
            int stateSize = statePart1.Length + statePart2.Length + 2; // Gets the state string size
            var state = string.Format("{0} {1}", statePart1, statePart2); // Creates the state string
            var city = e.Substring(0, e.Length - stateSize); // Gets the city string
            entries.Add(new string[] { state, city }); // Adds the entry to the entries
        }
        else
        {
            // If statePart1 is not valid then the state is a single "word"
            int cityLength = e.LastIndexOf(' '); // Gets the length of the city
            entries.Add(new string[] { statePart2, e.Substring(0, cityLength) }); // Adds the entry to the entries
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // If there is only two entries then both the city and state has only one "word"
        entries.Add(new string[] { entry[1], entry[0] }); // Adds the entry to the entries
    }
}
```

You can use the entries like this after

```
foreach (var e in entries)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", e[0], e[1]);
```

Which could result in something like:

```
string str = @"Grand Rapids New Mexico
Grand Rapids, NM
New York City New York
Jacksonville Florida
Bismarck North Dakota
Las Vegas Nevada";
```

Output ...

```
New Mexico, Grand Rapids
NM, Grand Rapids
New York, New York City
Florida, Jacksonville
North Dakota, Bismarck
Nevada, Las Vegas
```

Of course this is assuming you're parsing American states / cities.